# Query Overpass API by building name

Tags: overpass-api

Is there any way I can query overpass api by a building name

I was thinking of filtering nodes based on 
Country
Place
Postal Code

And after that I could search for the building name within the results, If i cannot do that directly

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can query for all buildings with a certain name tag. The [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) query wizard will generate something like this:

```
way["building"]["name"="Lake House"]({{bbox}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query buildings (and many other types, such as roads, highway, service, etc) with the name tag `building` by using [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/). For example, I use lines below to query all buildings in Hanoi (Vietnam's captital):

```
[out:csv ("name")][timeout:2500];
{{geocodeArea:Hanoi}}->.searchArea;
(
  way["building"]["name"](area.searchArea);
);
for (t["name"])
{
  make street name=_.val;
  out;
}
```

source: [here](https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?pid=841519#p841519)